# Typeerror valid is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal that has textboxes in it, and if a user did not input any details in the textbox, I want it to not save the record. I have a notiflix confirmation popup that will ask the user before they will save the record. The problem is if one of the textboxes has no details and I press save, it will show an error `$(...).valid() is not a function`

Here is my code

```
    if ($('#insertmain').valid()){ //insertmain is the id of modal
```

References:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You've to load jQuery before Validate library.

Comment: @Teemu it did not work

Comment: Is `#insertmain` a form element?

Comment: yes it is inside a form element

Comment: According to [jQuery Validation documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/), it looks like `#insertmain` should be a form element, not a form control element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in this way as you are using valid function before jquery library

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. It seems I have a different jquery reference in Layout.cshtml and I just need to remove that. It works now but validate is always returning true even if I leave empty spaces on a textarea.

Comment: mark as correct or close